# Java Spring Security - The constructor Security Properties User is not defined

Tags: java, hibernate, authentication, spring-security

I get this error message:

> Error: The constructor SecurityProperties.User(String, String,
>   boolean, boolean, boolean, boolean, List) is
>   undefined

This is my code:

```
package org.launchcode.shopcartsbh.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.launchcode.shopcartsbh.dao.AccountDAO;
import org.launchcode.shopcartsbh.entity.Account;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private AccountDAO accountDAO;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Account account = accountDAO.findAccount(username);
    System.out.println("Account= " + account);

    if (account == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " //
                + username + " was not found in the database");
    }

    // EMPLOYEE,MANAGER,..
    String role = account.getUserRole();

    List<GrantedAuthority> grantList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    // ROLE_EMPLOYEE, ROLE_MANAGER
    GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role);

    grantList.add(authority);

    String user = account.getUserName();
    String password = account.getEncrytedPassword();

    boolean enabled = account.isActive();
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

****   UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) new User(user, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, grantList); 
**** this is where the error is

    return userDetails;
}

}
```

I was wondering if their was some way I could rewrite this to make it more functional? I have been researching this for the past couple of days and still with no solution in sight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You imported the wrong `User`class, should be

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
```

instead of

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties.User;
```